# Replacing dataframe values after removing/replacing character in rows using Pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, substitution

I have a dataframe `df_in` like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dic_in = {'A':['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','uu','xx','yy','zz'],
       'B':['200','200','AA200','AA040',np.nan,'500',np.nan,'0700','900','UKK','200'],
       'C':['UNN','400',np.nan,'AA080','AA800','B',np.nan,'400',np.nan,'500','UKK']}
```

My goal is to investigate column `B` and `C` in such a way that:

- If one of the items contains the following character `'AA'`, then the number such part of the string must be removed leaving only the numeric part. (`AA123 ---> 123`). If a zeros are present before the first non null element, they must be removed (`AA001234 ---> 1234`).
- if the quantity is not a number then it must be set to `0.0` (`NaN ---> 0.0`, `UNN ----> 0.0`, `UKK ---> 0.0` and so on).
- if an item has leading zeros before, then they must be deleted (`070--->700`, `00007000--->7000`)
- If an item has been modified and is non-zero then it must be multiplied by `100`.

The final result should look like this:

```
   # BEFORE #                     # AFTER #
     A      B      C               A      B      C
0   aa    200    UNN          0   aa    200    0.0
1   bb    200    400          1   bb    200    400
2   cc  AA200    NaN          2   cc  20000    0.0
3   dd  AA040  AA080          3   dd   4000   8000
4   ee    NaN  AA800          4   ee    0.0  80000
5   ff    500      B          5   ff    500    0.0
6   gg    NaN    NaN          6   gg    0.0    0.0
7   uu   0700    400          7   uu    700    400
8   xx    900    NaN          8   xx    900    0.0
9   yy    UKK    500          9   yy    0.0    500
10  zz    200    UKK          10  zz    200    0.0
```

Do you know a smart and efficient way to achieve such goal?

**Notice**: all the numbers are in reality string and they should remain as so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) for replace not numeric to `NaN`.

Then [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) numbers from strings, remove `0` from left by [`lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html) and add `00`.

Last [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and assign to columns:

```
b = pd.to_numeric(df_in.B, errors='coerce')
c = pd.to_numeric(df_in.C, errors='coerce')

b1 = df_in.B.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).str.lstrip('0') + '00'
c1 = df_in.C.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).str.lstrip('0') + '00'

df_in.B = b.combine_first(b1).fillna(0)
df_in.C = c.combine_first(c1).fillna(0)
print (df_in)
     A      B      C
0   aa    200      0
1   bb    200    400
2   cc  20000      0
3   dd   4000   8000
4   ee      0  80000
5   ff    500      0
6   gg      0      0
7   uu    700    400
8   xx    900      0
9   yy      0    500
10  zz    200      0
```

A bit modified solution last [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by string `0.0` convert all values to strings (avoid some strings and some numeric values):

```
b = pd.to_numeric(df_in.B, errors='coerce')
c = pd.to_numeric(df_in.C, errors='coerce')

b1 = df_in.B.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).str.lstrip('0') + '00'
c1 = df_in.C.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).str.lstrip('0') + '00'

df_in.B = b.combine_first(b1)
df_in.C = c.combine_first(c1)

df_in = df_in.fillna('0.0').astype(str)
print (df_in)
     A      B      C
0   aa  200.0    0.0
1   bb  200.0  400.0
2   cc  20000    0.0
3   dd   4000   8000
4   ee    0.0  80000
5   ff  500.0    0.0
6   gg    0.0    0.0
7   uu  700.0  400.0
8   xx  900.0    0.0
9   yy    0.0  500.0
10  zz  200.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the values in your dataframe are strings (including the `NaN`s, otherwise you can convert them to an appropriate string with `fillna`), you can use the following `converter` function with `applymap` on the two columns you want to convert.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dic_in, dtype=str).fillna('NAN')

converter = lambda x: str(int(x.replace('AA', ''))*100) if 'AA' in x else str(int(x)) if x.isdigit() else '0.0'

df[['B','C']] = df[['B','C']].applymap(converter)
```

contents of `df`:

```
     A      B      C
0   aa    200    0.0
1   bb    200    400
2   cc  20000    0.0
3   dd   4000   8000
4   ee    0.0  80000
5   ff    500    0.0
6   gg    0.0    0.0
7   uu    700    400
8   xx    900    0.0
9   yy    0.0    500
10  zz    200    0.0
```